# Type erased on implicit evidence check

Tags: scala, generics, type-erasure

I'm trying to create a poor man version of [refined types](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) implementation with a simple validation of string content and check the return type via `Implicit` evidence on another function. It seems that the type got erased after it got returned from the `check` function. Can someone suggest me an scala trick to do this effectively?

```
sealed trait Validate
sealed trait Pass extends Validate
sealed trait Fail extends Validate
type SUCCESS = Pass
case class Validator[State <: Validate: TypeTag](s: String = "") {

  def check = {
    if (s == "awesome") {
      Validator[Pass](s)
    } else {
      Validator[Fail](s)
    }
  }

  def pass: Validator[Pass] = Validator[Pass](s)
  def fail: Validator[Fail] = Validator[Fail](s)

  def validate(implicit ev: State =:= SUCCESS): String = s
  def testResult = typeOf[State] =:= typeOf[SUCCESS]

}

Validator("awesome").check.testResult // true
Validator("awesome").check.validate // Cannot prove that _1 =:= MdocApp.this.SUCCESS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your goal correctly you'd like to replace the implementation using `scala-reflect` `TypeTag` (`testResult`) with the one using static-types and implicits (`validate`).

The return type of `check` is just `Validator[Validate]`, not `Validator[Pass]` or `Validator[Fail]`.

Types are resolved at compile time, so compiler has to know whether a string is `"awesome"` at compile time. For example you can lift `s` to type level.
A string having type `String` is too rough, you can use precise singleton subtypes instead. You can introduce a type class for compile-time "pattern matching"

```
// type class
trait Check[S <: String] {
  type State <: Validate
}
trait LowPriorityCheck {
  type Aux[S <: String, State0 <: Validate] = Check[S] {type State = State0 }
  implicit def default[S <: String]: Aux[S, Fail] = null
}
object Check extends LowPriorityCheck {
  implicit val pass: Aux["awesome", Pass] = null
}

case class Validator[S <: String with Singleton, State <: Validate](s: S) {
  def check(implicit check: Check[S]): Validator[S, check.State] =
    Validator[S, check.State](s)

  def validate(implicit ev: State =:= SUCCESS): String = s
}

Validator("awesome").check.validate // awesome

Validator("abc").check.validate //  Cannot prove that Fail =:= SUCCESS
```

If you prefer to keep both implementations you can restore `TypeTag` context bounds. Then you'll have to make method `check` generic. It's better to make `State` a type parameter of the type class rather than type member (otherwise there will be an error *"cannot create a `TypeTag` referring to type `LowPriorityCheck.<refinement>.State` local to the reifee: use `WeakTypeTag` instead"* but using `WeakTypeTag`/`weakTypeOf` instead of `TypeTag`/`typeOf` is too finest, `weakTypeOf[State] =:= typeOf[SUCCESS]` is never true).

```
trait Check[S <: String, State <: Validate]
trait LowPriorityCheck {
  implicit def default[S <: String]: Check[S, Fail] = null
}
object Check extends LowPriorityCheck {
  implicit val pass: Check["awesome", Pass] = null
}

case class Validator[S <: String with Singleton, State <: Validate: TypeTag](s: S) {
  def check[St <: Validate : TypeTag](implicit 
    check: Check[S, St]
  ): Validator[S, St] = Validator[S, St](s)
  //def check[St <: Validate : Check[S, *] : TypeTag]: Validator[S, St] = Validator[S, St](s)

  def testResult = typeOf[State] =:= typeOf[SUCCESS]

  def validate(implicit ev: State =:= SUCCESS): String = s
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Do you think it's possible to make a more dynamic validation instead comparing to a constant "awesome" (e.g string.length > 5) using this approach? I'm guessing no as the compiler will not be able to do it on compile time..